# Перегрузка оператора умножения для разных типов

Tags: c++, функции, классы, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Дана задача: реализовать класс "Комплексное число", поля класса: действительная и мнимая части. Одним из методов класса должна быть перегрузка оператора умножения для двух комплексных чисел и для комплексного и вещественного числа. В классе действительная и мнимая части задаются переменными типа double.
Получилось создать класс с рабочим методом для перемножения двух комплексных чисел, приведу его код:

```
complex_number complex_number :: operator * (complex_number second_multiplier)
{
    complex_number operation_result;
    operation_result.Re = Re * second_multiplier.Re - Im * second_multiplier.Im;
    operation_result.Im = Im * second_multiplier.Re + Re * second_multiplier.Im;
    return operation_result;
}
```

Однако не совсем понимаю, как реализовать перегрузку для того, чтобы на вход можно было дать вещественное число, так как операции для него будут другими, да и тип параметра тоже, т. е. чтобы работало не только

```
complex_number a, b, c;
//... задание значений переменных a и b
c = a * b;
```

но и

```
c = a * 2.5;
```

Думаю, что нужно использовать шаблоны, но не представляю, как это реализовать.

Comment: Можно отдельный оператор дописать. А можно положиться на конструктор `complex_number(double)`. Без шаблонов. А если из класса вынести, то еще и `2.5*a` можно будет множить :)

Answer (score 1):

Реализация того, что я написал в комментарии.

```
class Complex
{
    double re, im;

public:

    Complex(double re = 0.0, double im = 0.0):re(re),im(im) {}
    Complex(const Complex& c) = default;
    ~Complex() = default;
    Complex& operator=(const Complex& c)
    {
        this->re = c.re;  this->im = c.im;
        return *this;
    }
    friend Complex operator+(const Complex&a, const Complex& b);
    friend Complex operator-(const Complex&a, const Complex& b);
    friend Complex operator*(const Complex&a, const Complex& b);

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Complex& b);

};


Complex operator+(const Complex&a, const Complex& b)
{
    return Complex{a.re+b.re, a.im+b.im};
}
Complex operator-(const Complex&a, const Complex& b)
{
    return Complex{a.re-b.re, a.im-b.im};
}
Complex operator*(const Complex&a, const Complex& b)
{
    return Complex{a.re*b.re - a.im*b.im, a.im*b.re + a.re*b.im};
}
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Complex& b)
{
    return os << "(" << b.re << "," << b.im << ")";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Complex c{4,5}, d{2,1};

    Complex a = c + 1;
    Complex b = 2 + c;
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;

    a = c*d + 3*a + b*4;

    cout << a << endl;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я добавил в свой код дополнительную перегрузку для переменных типа double. Но я не понимаю, как в вашем коде работает перегрузка для переменной типа double перед переменной complex

Comment: Все просто - компилятор смотрит на `5*a`, выясняет, какие есть операторы умножения с участием `a` - только `Complex*Complex`. А есть ли возможность привести `5` к `Complex`? А есть - конструктор от `double` (второй `double` равен 0 по умолчанию). Нет ли неоднозначностей, другого способа приведения? Нет. Значит, умножаем как `Complex(5)*a`. Все.